# Creating DLL in VSCode

Tags: winapi, dll, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make dlls outside of Visual Studio and specifically in VSCode?
The tutorials I found were not helpful in this regard.
Any useful extension recommendations will also be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong tool. Research how to build a DLL from the command line using your chosen toolchain, then configure your build task to do *that* (like pretty-much everything else in vscode).

Comment: Which article did you follow? Do you have Windows SDK installed? Which type of method will be easy for your project?